# Pasar datos de una view a otra con protocol's

Tags: swift

Teniendo el siguiente código:

ViewController2:

```
import UIKit

protocol TransferirTexto {

    func transferir(texto : String)

}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var delegate : TransferirTexto?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




    @IBAction func transferirDato(sender: AnyObject) {

        delegate?.transferir(textField.text!)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
```

ViewController1:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, TransferirTexto {

    @IBOutlet weak var miLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



    func transferir(texto: String) {
        miLabel.text = texto
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        svc.delegate = self

    }

}
```

¿Como funciona el tema de los delegados en este caso?
Al cambiar de un viewController a otro, no se destruye el primer viewController? La duda surge de como hago para pasarle un `.delegate = self` si el viewController se va a destruir?

Comment: Hola MatiEzelQ, por favor en lugar de dejar una imagen, agrega el código como texto y confía en el syntax highlighter. Tus compañeros invidentes que usen un lector de texto a voz te lo agradecerán

Comment: Tenes razón, ahi lo cambio.

Comment: No, el _view controller_ no se destruye... ¿Qué error te dio el código así como lo tienes ahora?

Comment: Ningún error. No entiendo si se instancias todos los controllers al momento de iniciar la app o cuando y si la cambio, si se destruyen o quedan en memoria.

Answer (score 1):

Es sencillo , te dejo un ejemplo para que veas el funcionamiento.

ViewController 1:

```
 class ViewController1 : UIViewcontroller, MenuTableProtocol {
            if let menuTable = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MenuTableView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? MenuTableView {
                let items = ["Item1","Item2"]
                menuTable.items = items
                menuTable.tblDelegate = self //Aqui le estamos diciendo que yo Viewcontroller1 me hago cargo del delegado
                self.view.addSubview(menuTable)
            }

/**
    Aqui implementamos la función del Protocolo que nos interesa manejar
    */
    func didSelect(referenceItem: String) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(referenceItem)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

ViewController 2:

```
    class ViewController2 : UIViewController {
//Lo siguiente sirve para que al instanciar la clase ViewController2 el controlador que quiera se puede hacer cargo de este protocolo
        var tblDelegate:MenuTableProtocol!

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) {
            //Aqui estamos empujando al delegado a que actúe
            self.tblDelegate.didSelect!(items[indexPath.row].reference)
        }

    }
```

-Como te han dicho ViewController1 y ViewController2 siguen existiendo , en ningún momento se borran de la stack , simplemente crean una conexión entre ambos y se comunican , que es para eso para lo que sirven los Protocolos.
Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Primero se instancia el `ViewController1`.

Desde ahí instancias el segundo en el `prepareForSegue`.

Ahí tienes los 2 controladores cargados, no se ha destruido ninguno.

Con el `svc.delegate = self` le indicas al `ViewContrller2` como pude acceder al `ViewController1` (el delegado no deja de ser una puntero al otro controlador).

Desde el `ViewController2`, cuando le pasas la información al primero usando `delegate?transferir(textField.text!)`, ese puntero sigue apuntando al `ViewController1`, así que le llega la información y cuando haces el `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` es cuando se descarga el `ViewController2`, pero no el `ViewController1`.

Otra cosa importante que debes hacer es cuando declares el delegado hazlo así:

```
weak var delegate : TransferirTexto?
```

Imagínate que los delegados están apuntados al revés, en lugar que `ViewController2` tenga un delegado apuntando a `ViewController1`, es `ViewController1` el que tiene un `delegate = ViewController2` y en un momento determinado haces un `popViewControllerAnimated` y el `ViewController2` desaparece.

Desde `ViewController1` sigues teniendo el delegado apuntando a algo que ya no existe, y eso no le gusta nada a **Swift**. Al ponerlo `weak`, cuando se destruye ViewController2, el delegado se queda en `null`, así que al ser opcional cuando lo ejecutes no hace ni pasa nada